# Reading TEMPERATURE_TARGET directly from CPU

Tags: python, c++, c, cpu-registers

I would like to directly read the minimum temperate at which the TCC will be activated from the TEMPERATURE_TARGET register in my Intel i7-5930k. The Socket Thermal Guide (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/core-i7-lga2011-3-tmsdg.html) from intel says there is a software readable field in the TEMPERATURE_TARGET register. Is there a way to read this field to get the absolute processor Temperature in Linux using either a command line tool or a writing some code?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the OS.

On linux, you can read it using `rdmsr` (read model
specific registers)

On ubuntu, you could try something like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install msr-tools
sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:8 -c 0x00001a2
sudo rdmsr --bitfield 23:16 -c 0x00001a2
```

Returns `0x12` and `0x69` on my machine.

**Explanation**

From the [Thermal Mechanical Design Guidelines](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-tmsdg.pdf) (page 20):

> 1. Temperature Control (T_CONTROL ) Offset: MSR (1A2h)
>      TEMPERATURE_TARGET[15:8]
> 2. TCC Activation Temperature: MSR (1A2h) TEMPERATURE_TARGET[23:16]

- `0x00001a2` is the register number.
- The first `rdmsr` command reads the field *Temperature Control Offset*.
- The second `rdmsr` command reads the field *TCC Activation Temperature*.

Comment: All the extreme core guide has is (page 29)
'Bit        Attrib      Default    Description
31:16   RSVD-P  0000h     Reserved--Protected
15:0     R0-V      0000h     THERM_MARGIN--This field provides Platform Firmware with running average of the instantaneous
temperature margin above Tspec in 2's complement
8.8 format. 
Note - DTS 2.0 Thermal Margin CSR is a mirror of MSR (1A1h) PACKAGE_THERM_MARGIN'

would that make the command
sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:0 -c 0x00001a1 ? 
For that I get CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x00001a1

Comment: @LeonLewis Have you tried `sudo rdmsr --bitfield 15:0 -c 0x0000000`?