# read TDP and T JUNCTION from CPU

Tags: c#, .net, temperature, openhardwaremonitor

I'm creating a c# WinForm to check CPU (mostly current Intel processors) behavior under load to detect cooling issues. I'm using openhardwaremonitor.dll to get temperature, load and other stuff. Now the first issue is, how to get Tjunction (max allowed temperature) to compare with, because this value differs from CPU to CPU.
My current workaround is a configfile, where I can enter that value collected from Intel Arc.
The question here is, is this information stored (sure it is) in a readable (from .NET) value?

The second question is, if first answer is yes, can TDP be read the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU does not stores or inform TDP.
It is really necessary to get TDP from the specs (ARC) for your specific CPU part number.
Note that TDP spec is the minimum and exact value varies from unit to unit.
In regards to TjMax you can get it from the register TEMPERATURE_TARGET.
I suggest you take a look in this thread:

[Reading TEMPERATURE_TARGET directly from CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400005/reading-temperature-target-directly-from-cpu)